# show images inserted in comma format to the database in one field

Tags: php, mysql, image

How can i show or echo image which is inserted in comma format like this

[image]

When i m inserting 1 image

```
<img src="images/<?php echo row['image'];?>" >
```

this code is running fine.. But when i m inserting more than 1 image at a time. its not showing any image.. Should i use rtrim or explode  to remove commas & show images.. any help .. ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: would you like to display multiple images?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing multiple images within the same field to begin with. Rework your database structure so you only have one have one image per field. You're creating your own structure within each field. Let the database handle that.

Comment: actualy i m inserting images through javascript,, so i need to store multiple image in one fld @kba

Comment: @sarmistha Under no circumstances do you need to store multiple images in one field. The source is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explode the return data in an array and then need to display them, something as

```
$images = explode(",",$row['image']);

if(sizeof($images) > 0 ){
  foreach($images as $image){
   echo '<img src="images/'.$image.'">' ;
   echo "<br />"; 
  }
}
```

You can style the display of images separation as you want instead of BR as in my exapmple

Answer (score 0):

Well.. how do you want to show multiple images in the same  tag?
Loop trough them:

```
$images = explode(',', $row['images']);
foreach($images as $img)
{
   echo '<img src="images/' .$img .'" >';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them then loop through them

```
$img = explode("," $row['image']);
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($img); $i++){
    echo "<img src=\"images/" . $img[$i] . "\" >";
}
```

But you should really normalize your table/database so many images have 1 or more parent id